# What is the default URL for APEX for an Oracle XE installation?

Tags: oracle-apex

I've installed Oracle XE with APEX, but forgot to write down the URL to access it.  How may I determine the URL?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default is http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex

If you happen to be on Windows, there will also be an entry in the Start menu (Programs > Oracle XE > Database homepage )

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, to get to the Apex Administration Services:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/apex_admin